# Does PHP work only with forms?

Tags: php, forms, single-page-application

I started a PHP course today and my teacher told me that PHP works only with forms...
Is it true? 
I want to create a geolocation SPA. Is it possible to do that with PHP?

Comment: You probably want to find a new teacher (sooner rather than later). Their assertion is simply not true at all.

Comment: Thank you Dave. You safe me money. Have a nice day.

Comment: 95% of [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com) is in PHP. Does facebook contains only forms?

Comment: ...btw the downvotes on this question (would be nice if downvoters could leave comments, telling why) are probably because of this: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Answer (score 1):

PHP is a server-side language with which you can make the server send back any output you like.

The combination JavaScript on the Client and PHP on the server is often used to generate SPA's. Work which must be done on the server (calculations, data base requests) are often implemented via PHP and work which can be done on the client (rendering graphics, updating page elements) are implemented in JavaScript.

## School book case: PHP returning HTML

Your teacher is probably referring to an example like this taken from W3schools.com, [click for live demo](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp)

index.html:

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

welcome.php

```
<html>
<body>

Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

So the form in index.html requests welcome.php from the server, which is a mixture of HTML and PHP. It calls PHP for all the `<?php ... ?>` parts, embeds the result into the remaining HTML page and sends that back. So the response from the Server is a HTML page.

## Use PHP's `echo`, JavaScript to get non-HTML output from the server -> SPA

Consider this example [from W3Schools.com (click for live demo)](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp?):

PHP generates no HTML output, but simple text. The result for `http://example.com/gethint.php?q=sometext` is just a plain string and not HTML like in the previous example. But the request is not done by the browser in attempt to get an HTML page. Instead, Javascript on the main page does the request and embeds the result into the already loaded page on the browser.

### index.html

This is the Web site (application front end). It displays a text field in which you can enter text. Via javascript a request is sent to the server which runs PHP. It sends back a simple string which contains possible names which match the input.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showHint(str) {
    if (str.length == 0) { 
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "gethint.php?q=" + str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p><b>Start typing a name in the input field below:</b></p>
<form> 
First name: <input type="text" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)">
</form>
<p>Suggestions: <span id="txtHint"></span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

### gethint.php

This is the PHP running on a server. You see that the whole file is enclosed in one big `<?php ... ?>`, not like in `welcome.php` above. Here, the output is not generated by replacing a small `<?php ... ?>` tag with its value, but by the function `echo`.

```
<?php
// Array with names
$a[] = "Anna";
$a[] = "Brittany";
// ... lots of names ...
$a[] = "Wenche";
$a[] = "Vicky";

// get the q parameter from URL
$q = $_REQUEST["q"];

$hint = "";

// lookup all hints from array if $q is different from "" 
if ($q !== "") {
    $q = strtolower($q);
    $len=strlen($q);
    foreach($a as $name) {
        if (stristr($q, substr($name, 0, $len))) {
            if ($hint === "") {
                $hint = $name;
            } else {
                $hint .= ", $name";
            }
        }
    }
}

// Output "no suggestion" if no hint was found or output correct values 
echo $hint === "" ? "no suggestion" : $hint;
?>
```

Therefore, in principle there is no limit as for what can be done with PHP

Comment: Thank you very much mate, I understand more now.

Comment: @Neotrius glad to hear that. If you find a answer on Stack Overflow useful, you can upvote the answer (you can do this with every answer, not only in your own question) and the question (if it's not from you). Thereby, you help others find the best answers.

Comment: I will upvote for sure but I don't have enough points atm.
Thank you.